# AppService VNET Integration Fails with VNET is already occupied

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I had an older version of appservice Plan which was connected to a VNET/Subnet . When i wanted to upgrade it to VNET integration the appservice plan was completely deleted. But when i try to redeploy the App service plan using the same VNET/Subnet this fails with below error.

````
Status Message: {
 "Code": "Conflict",
 "Message": "Subnet xxx-subnet in VNET xxx-vnet is already occupied by service ***/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/shared.",
 "Target": null,
 "Details": [
 {
 "Message": "Subnet xxx-subnet in VNET xxx-vet is already occupied by service ***/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/shared."
 },
 {
 "Code": "Conflict"
 },
 {
 "ErrorEntity": {
 "ExtendedCode": "55914",
 "MessageTemplate": "Subnet {0} in VNET {1} is already occupied by service {2}.",
 "Parameters": [
 "xxxx-subnet",
 "xxxx-t-vnet",
 "***/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/shared"
 ],
 "Code": "Conflict",
 "Message": "xxxx-subnet in VNET xxxx-t-vnet is already occupied by service ***/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/shared."
 }
 }
 ],
 "Innererror": null
} (Code:DeploymentOperationFailed)```


Not sure how we can proceed here as cannot find the older app service plan in Portal as well.
````

Comment: I also get this....works from Azure portal but fails from ARM template

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the discussion, looks like the subnet has serviceAssociationLink property set on it. This property is initialized by the Microsoft.Web resource provider on the integration subnet, when the first Web App in an App Service Plan is integrated with the subnet.

You can view this property via **[Azure Resource explorer](https://resources.azure.com)**

Look at the link attribute under that property and you will see that it will have a reference to an App Service Plan. Here is a screenshot from mine.

[image]

You can log a support ticket with Azure support and they can help you clear the ServiceAssociationLink on that subnet.

Answer (score 0):

On the Subnet that you're deploying the App service too, can you try changing the "Subnet Delegation" to "None".

This way, the subnet is not dedicated to a specific service, then anything should connect to it. You can then try re-adding the "Subnet Delegation" back to "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms".

Comment: let me try this one and test it

Comment: Failed to save subnet 'xxxx-subnet'. Error: 'Subnet xxxx-vnets-t-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/xxxx-t-vnet/subnets/xxxx-subnet'>xxxx-t-vnet/xxxx-subnet requires any of the following delegation(s) [Microsoft.Web/serverFarms] to reference service association link xxxx-vnets-t-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/xxxx-t-vnet/subnets/xxx-subnet/serviceAssociationLinks/AppServiceLink

Comment: Okay. When you re-deploy it, have you been using the same resource name as when it got deleted? Have a look at this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/140197/unable-to-delete-vnet-due-to-serviceassociationlin.html. But in your case, you would skip step 4 and 5 as you want to keep the connection around.

Comment: sorry if late, but see my response. It is a common cause of such problems.